# Eclipse not compiling additional jar files

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, compilation

Eclipse has stopped compiling the jar files to my android project, when i deploy it to the device or create a build the reference are not found correctly

Could not find class 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity', referenced from method com.xyz.trySomthing()

I have the httpClient, httpCore, httpMime etc required jar's. It used to work fine previously but not all the jar files or external libraries are not getting referenced correctly.

Same thing happens for Twitter Jar

---

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at com.xyz.abc.abcd.askOAuth(BestOf.java:564)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at com.xyz.abc.abcd.access$0(BestOf.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at com.xyz.abc.abcd$3$1.onClick(BestOf.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:873)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:647)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2175):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: azertiti is correct, just need to rename lib to libs. Apparently it was problem with adt upgrade to version 17. Drop all the required jars/libraries into libs folder and it will be automatically updated to your code. No need to configure build path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create a folder "libs" in your project ADT will automatically use them. I had the same problem, in an older version of ADT it was working fine with an external project but now it was giving me NoClassDefFoundError. The solution was to create a jar and place it in "libs" folder.

Comment: don't you think you also need to right-click on jar file (which is in libs folder) and select **Build Path->Add to Build Path**?

Comment: If you use the "libs" folder you don't have to do that, it's automated. This has been added in ADT 17, check: http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects The "libs" folder is where the depending library jars are also added and included in the final APK.

Comment: ahaan, haven't used ADT17 yet, but might be true :)

Comment: You don't need to put jars into the libs folder if you right click on the project, chose "build path"->"configure build path"->"order and Export" and check the boxes for the relevant jar files

Comment: Just put the jars in the libs folder, it's the recommended method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed out 6 month from Android development and the new ADT is giving me a hard time.

Comment: Ok, now I have the problem again, jars in the libs folder, Java version set to 1.6, and this solution is not working for org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity . I added every library from apache, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Adding .jars to build path should help without moving to Libs folder.

Simply open "Project Properties" -> "Java Build Path" and check whether all desired .jars are ticked in "Order and export tab".